# Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_String issue with SQL query

Tags: php, sql, syntax-error, parse-error

Im getting this error:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'listings' (T_STRING) in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\get_venues.php</b> on line 
<b>30</b>
<br />
```

Here is the corresponding PHP line:

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Venue_ID IN (SELECT Venue_ID FROM venues WHERE Venue_Name = $VenueName AND Region = $Region) AND Event_ID IN (SELECT Event_ID FROM events WHERE Event_Name = $VenueName AND Category = $Category);
```

Can anyone work out where im going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing quotes here: `Event_Name = $VenueName AND Category = $Category`.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your string in quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Venue_ID IN (SELECT Venue_ID FROM venues WHERE Venue_Name = $VenueName AND Region = $Region) AND Event_ID IN (SELECT Event_ID FROM events WHERE Event_Name = $VenueName AND Category = $Category");
```